# Rendering JSP in ALLOY DIALOG

Tags: liferay

I am using ALLOY DIALOG in Liferay 6.0.5 as follows:

function countPopup(){

```
AUI().use('aui-dialog', 'liferay-portlet-url', function(A) {

        var dialog = new A.Dialog({
        title: 'Upload Details',
        centered: true,
        modal: true,
        width: 500,
        height: 400,
        bodyContent:"testing",

        }).render();

    });
```

}

I am getting in popup " testing ". But Instead of "bodycontent" I want to forward to one jsp file where i have written some logic. How to do that?

Comment: Yes. I got it. we have to use like this to render to jsp through ALLOY popup:

Answer (score 3):

You must "plug" another module to feed a.Dialog with article desired.
Try some like this:

```
AUI().use('aui-dialog', 'aui-io', function(A) {

    var dialog = new A.Dialog({
    title: 'Upload Details',
    centered: true,
    modal: true,
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    }).plug(A.Plugin.IO, {uri: 'your_url.html'}).render();

});
```

Comment: I had tried your solution, but I'm getting error in JavaScript. this is the error Uncaught ReferenceError: test_content is not defined. Where test_content is the content of page that I want to access

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too much late to give answer to this question but here is the solution.

```
<%

User selUser = (User)request.getAttribute("user.selUser");
PortletURL popupURL = renderResponse.createRenderURL();
popupURL.setWindowState(LiferayWindowState.POP_UP);
popupURL.setParameter("jspPage","Your jsp page path here"); 
String popup = "javascript:xyzPopUp('"+ popupURL.toString() + "');";%>


<aui:script>
Liferay.provide(
    window,
    'xyzPopUp',
    function(url) {
        var A = AUI();  
        var portletURL="<%=themeDisplay.getURLManageSiteMemberships().toString()%>";
        var dialog = new A.Dialog(
            {
                modal: true,
                centered: true,
                destroyOnClose: true,
                draggable: true,
                height: 150,
                resizable: false,
                title: 'your title here',
                width: 200
            }
        ).plug(
            A.Plugin.IO,
                {
                    uri:url
                }
        ).render();
    },
    ['aui-dialog']
); 
</aui:script>
```

This will open the given jsp page in to popup.